# Oracle bug with multiple outer joins and a case statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting what appears to be a bizarre bug with Oracle 11.2.0.2.0. Everything tells me that this must be a bug, but I haven't been able to find mentions of it and it's a common enough use case that you would think that it would have been found and fixed long before now. Things work fine in the RDS version of Oracle (12-something) which lends credence to my opinion that it must be a bug.

I've been able to reproduce the issue with nothing but selects from `dual`, so no tables need to be added to test this. Consider the following SQL:

```
select t2.*

from (
  select 1 as id from "DUAL"
) t1

left outer join (
  select 2 as id, 10 as foo from "DUAL"
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id

left outer join (
  select
    1 as id,
--     case when 1 = 1 then 10 else 7 end as foo,
    2 as bar
  from "DUAL"
) t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

It produces exactly the results you'd expect:

```
id    foo
--    ---
null  null
```

Since the first outer join fails (there is no row in `t2` with an id of 1), the columns are null as they should be. Notice I'm not even using the results of the second join. But if I uncomment the `case` statement, the results change!

```
id    foo
--    ---
2     10
```

Here are some things I've observed so far:

- The results change if there are 1 or more additional outer joins in the query which also contain a `case` statement.
- It doesn't matter if the second outer join passes or fails.
- It only appears that literals in `t2`'s `select` statement have the issue. That is, if the `select` statement were something like `select id, 10 as foo from "MY_TABLE"`, `id` would be null as you'd expect but `foo` still is 10.

There are a couple of ways you can answer this question:

- If this is actually not a bug, can you explain why this is occurring and cite documentation explaining the behavior?
- If this is a bug, can you link to references to the bug and in what version of 11g that it was resolved in (if any)?

What I **don't** want are "this must be a bug because it violates such-and-such spec" answers. I already know this and I already completely agree with you. I need to know why it's happening (if it's not a bug) or where/when it was fixed if it is a bug.

If you have a version of Oracle where both versions of the query work properly, please leave a comment with the version number. It may be useful to find out what bug this was and when it was fixed.

Comment: I can't reproduce in 11.2.0.4. So it could be bug 12626914 or 13720740 which were both fixed in 11.2.0.4, or could be something else (I didn't look far down the list in MoS). You could raise an SR but as the first response is likely to be upgrade to 12c/18c, or at least to the terminal patch release of 11g (which is out of support not, of course), not sure how far that will get you.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks, I'll take a look. If it looks like it was either of those two I'll let you know so you can write an answer.

Comment: @AlexPoole jeez, Oracle really makes it impossible to find previous bugs online, don't they? Judging from the subject on the one result I did find (Wrong results with CASE statement with outer join), and due to the bug being fixed in 11.2.0.4 which coincides with your results, that has to be the issue. If you write up the answer I'll mark it as correct.